# Problems while doing dumbbell curl

Tags: dumbbells, curls

Currently I am a beginner in muscle building and to train my bicep muscles I am using dumbbells and I am performing dumbbell curls with them.

While performing the curls, after some reps my left arm wont fold completely and gets stuck in middle of the way, while the opposite arm folds completely. Due to this I have to use my shoulder muscle to make it fold, and which moves the tension from the bicep muscle to the shoulder. When doing barbell curl with both arms I can do 4 sets of 14 reps with 40kg, but when I do dumbbell curl with the right arm I can't even do 2 reps with 5kg. And my left arm, which is weaker, is able to do 12.5kg.

This happens with my right arm, which is my "strong arm". What can be the reason behind it and is there any way to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

It is not uncommon for one arm to be weaker than the other, even if they are both considered "strong". The reason for your right arm getting stuck in the middle of the curl could be due to a lack of flexibility or mobility in that arm, or it could be a weakness in the bicep muscle. It is important to focus on proper form and ensure that you are using the correct technique while performing the curls. Additionally, you may want to consider incorporating exercises that target the weaker arm specifically, such as isolated dumbbell curls, to help build strength and improve flexibility. Over time, with consistent practice and attention to technique, you may notice improvements in both arms. Remember to always listen to your body and make adjustments accordingly to prevent injury.

Here are some resources that can provide more information on how to build muscle and improve bicep strength:

- https://www.healthline.com/health/fitness-exercise/muscle-building-101
- https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/concentration-curls
- https://www.menshealth.com/fitness/a19544115/fix-bicep-imbalances-unilateral-exercises/
- https://blog.aqfsports.com/what-are-the-best-foods-to-eat-for-muscle-growth/

I hope you find these resources helpful in your journey to improve your bicep strength!